# How to request official documents from France of deceased parent?

Tags: france, eu-citizens, french-citizens

My father was born in 1958 and adopted. He traveled from France as a baby and moved to Germany. He is deceased. What pieces of identification or official french documents (besides the acte de naissance) would be available and where do I go to request it? I live in the United States.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as better suited to the expertise of those on [SEGeneology](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to keep this question open because even if genealogy experts at [Genealogy.SE] might be able to provide a better answer, people who need these kinds of documents for non-genealogical reasons (for example, to pursue French citizenship) will continue to come here to [Expatriates.SE] seeking answers.

Answer (score 1):

Where stated [in French](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F1412) on the websites of consulates, documents need to be translated into French by a certified translator, must be originals and be apostilled or legalised, as follows:

> Les documents en langue étrangère doivent faire l’objet d’une traduction assermentée en français. Il doit par ailleurs s’agir d’originaux ou de copies certifiées conformes à l’original par les autorités locaux. Les documents doivent être apostillés ou légalisés.

The [French Consulate in the US Nationality Department](https://washington.consulfrance.org/spip.php?article974) offers guidance on the process and a [contact form](https://washington.consulfrance.org/spip.php?article983) for enquiries.

> NB: The application files of CNF (Certificat de Nationalité Française) are to be sent directly to the Courts of Instance. e
>
> Each case is specific and the situations sometimes complex, the files are treated exclusively by appointment which it is necessary to take beforehand by e-mail.

The official directives can be found on [Service-Public.fr Le site officiel de l'administration française](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F1051) and on 
[Justice.fr Direction de l'information légale et administrative](http://www.justice.fr/fiche/certificat-nationalit%C3%A9-fran%C3%A7aise-cnf).