# What official documents would have been produced for a child born in France in 1958?

Tags: france, eu-citizens, french-citizens

My father is deceased. He was born in Orleans, France in 1958 to a French woman, was adopted as a baby and taken to Germany. I would like to find documents to confirm his identity, as his name was changed multiple times. What official documents, besides the acte de naissance, would have been produced for a baby in France around 1958--and where can I get them?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as better suited to the expertise of those on [SEGeneology](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a duplicate of https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/review/close/8991

Comment: @Dorothy being on topic elsewhere does not make a question off topic here.  I'm voting to keep this question open.

Comment: @ouflak you've linked to a review queue item, not a question?

Comment: Whoops! https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/10676/how-to-request-official-documents-from-france-of-deceased-parent